# Deriving the cost function from algorithm and proving their complexity is O(...)

Tags: algorithm

When computing algorithm costs with 1 for each operation, it gets confusing when `while` loops depend on more than one variable. This pseudo code inserts an element into the right place of a heap.

```
input: H[k]  // An array of size k, storing a heap
   e     // an element to insert
   s     // last element in array (s < k - 1)
output: Array H, e is inserted into H in the right place    

s = s+1                 [2]
H[s] = e                [3]
while s > 1:            ]       
   t=s/2                ][3]
   if H[s] < H[t]       ][3]    
     tmp = H[s]         ][3]
     H[s] = H[t]        ][3]
     H[t] = tmp         ][3]
     s = t              ][2]    
   else 
     break              ][1]

return H
```

What would be the cost function in terms of f(n)? and the Big *O* complexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I admit, I was initially confused by the indentation of your pseudo-code. After being prompted by [M.K's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54471385/deriving-the-cost-function-from-algorithm-and-proving-their-complexity-is-o/54471655?noredirect=1#comment95755865_54471655), I reindented your code, and understood what you meant about *more than one variable*.

Hint: If *s* is equal to *2<sup>k</sup>*, the loop will iterate *k* times, worst case. Expected average is *k/2* iterations.

The reason for *k/2* is that absent any other information, we assume the input *e* has equal chance of being any value between the current min and max of the array. If you know the distribution, then you can skew the expected average accordingly. Usually, though, the expected average will be constant factor of *k*, and so does not affect the big-*O*.

> Let *n* be the number of elements in the heap. So, the cost function *f(n)* represents the cost of the function for a heap of size *n*. The cost of the function outside of the while loop is constant *C<sub>1</sub>*, so *f(n)* is dominated by the while loop itself, *g(n)*. The cost of each iteration of the loop is also constant *C<sub>2</sub>*, so the cost is dependent on the number of iterations. So: *f(n)* = *C<sub>1</sub>* + *g(n+1)*. And *g(n)* = *C<sub>2</sub>* + *g(n/2)*. Now, you can solve the characteristic equation for *g(n)*. Note that *g(1)* is 0, and *g(2)* is *C<sub>2</sub>*.

The algorithm as presented uses swaps to sort of bubble the element up into the correct position. To make the inner loop more efficient (it doesn't change the complexity, mind you), the inner loop can instead behave more like an insertion sort would behave, and place the element in the right place only at the end.

```
s = s+1
while s > 1 and e < H[s/2]:
   H[s] = H[s/2];
   s = s/2;
H[s] = e;
```

Comment: I think in the best condition, `while`will iterate less times because of `s = t`, but I guess we need to stick always to the worst case, which it would be k times, right?

Comment: @M.K Expect new item to be less than half the numbers in the heap.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the while loop, you’ll observe that s divides itself by 2 until you reach 1.

Therefore the number of iterations will be equal to the log of s to the base 2.